# How to make rounded corner in drawLine in jetpack compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-canvas

I am using Canvas Api to draw something. I want to draw line with rounded corner. Line is draw without any problem. But I cannot figure out which attribute for corner radius.

```
val boxSize = 30.dp

Box(modifier = Modifier
            .background(Color.LightGray)
            .height(height = boxSize)
    ) {
        Canvas(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
        ) {
            val canvasWidth = size.width
            drawLine(
                start = Offset(x = 0f, y = (boxSize / 2).toPx()),
                end = Offset(x = canvasWidth, y = (boxSize / 2).toPx()),
                color = Color.Black,
                strokeWidth = 8.dp.toPx()
            )

        }
    }
```

My view is simple without corner radius.

[image]

I want my Black line to be corner for each side with specific radius.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to add the `cap` argument to `drawLine` and set it to `StrokeCap.Round`.

```
 drawLine(
     start = Offset(x = 0f, y = (boxSize / 2).toPx()),
     end = Offset(x = canvasWidth, y = (boxSize / 2).toPx()),
     color = Color.Black,
     strokeWidth = 8.dp.toPx(),
     cap = StrokeCap.Round, //add this line for rounded edges
)
```

Comment: How can I specific the radius of cap?

Comment: @VivekModi in this case you can't. It is based on the strokeWidth of the line.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 Box(
                    modifier = Modifier.padding(top = 4.dp, bottom = 4.dp).width(40.dp).height(3.dp).clip(shape = RoundedCornerShape(size = 5.dp)).background(Color.Red)
                )
```